# Null pointer excpetion with opencsv CsvToBean

Tags: java, csv, opencsv

I am trying to convert all rows in a CSV file into a java bean using openCSV.Each row has 21 columns in my file separated with pipe symbol(|).But getting null pointer exception with this code.rows in csv file include empty cells also.I am not able to figure out where is the error.can any one help me out

```
package com.alu.mdf.testsuite.sure;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.List;
import com.opencsv.CSVParser;
import com.opencsv.CSVReader;
import com.opencsv.bean.ColumnPositionMappingStrategy;
import com.opencsv.bean.CsvToBean;

//import com.alu.mdf.test.common.Person;

    public class CSVExplorer {

        @SuppressWarnings({"rawtypes", "unchecked"})
        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
        {
            CsvToBean csv = new CsvToBean();

            String csvFilename = "TestCaseConfigurationFiles/application.csv";
            //CSVReader csvReader = new CSVReader;
            CSVParser csvParser=new CSVParser('|');
            CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(csvFilename),1,csvParser);



            //Set column mapping strategy
            List list = csv.parse(setColumMapping(), reader);

            for (Object object : list) {
                SUREDataBean SUREDataBean = (SUREDataBean) object;
                System.out.println(SUREDataBean);
            }
        }

        @SuppressWarnings({"rawtypes", "unchecked"})
        private static ColumnPositionMappingStrategy setColumMapping() throws Exception
        {
            ColumnPositionMappingStrategy strategy = new ColumnPositionMappingStrategy();
            strategy.setType(SUREDataBean.class);
            //strategy.createBean();
            String[] columns = new String[] {"InputDataStartIdentifier","EntityType","Operation","IncludeId","IdValue","AssociatedResource","SearchQueryForGETRequest/ParametersForPUTRequest","PayloadLocation","TestCaseName","Description","userName","password","InputDataEndIdentifier","ValidationDataStart","ExpectedStatusCode","VerficationParameters","Method","class","Prerequisites","Group","ValidationDataEnd"};
            System.out.println(columns.length);
            strategy.setColumnMapping(columns);
            return strategy;
        }

    }
```

Here is error stack trace:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Error parsing CSV! at com.opencsv.bean.CsvToBean.parse(CsvToBean.java:95) at com.opencsv.bean.CsvToBean.parse(CsvToBean.java:75) at com.alu.mdf.testsuite.sure.CSVExplorer.main(CSVExplorer.java:28) Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException at com.opencsv.bean.CsvToBean.processLine(CsvToBean.java:123) at com.opencsv.bean.CsvToBean.processLine(CsvToBean.java:101) at com.opencsv.bean.CsvToBean.parse(CsvToBean.java:91) ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you'll have less trouble with [uniVocity-parsers](http://www.univocity.com/pages/parsers-tutorial). It is also way faster than OpenCSV. To use it, first annotate your bean:

```
class SUREDataBean {

    @NullString(nulls = { "?", "-" }) // if the value parsed in the quantity column is "?" or "-", it will be replaced by null.
    @Parsed(defaultNullRead = "0") // if a value resolves to null, it will be converted to the String "0".
    private Integer quantity; // The attribute name will be matched against the column header in the file automatically.

    @Trim
    @LowerCase
    @Parsed
    private String comments;
    ...

}
```

To parse:

```
BeanListProcessor<SUREDataBean> rowProcessor = new BeanListProcessor<SUREDataBean>(SUREDataBean.class);

CsvParserSettings parserSettings = new CsvParserSettings();
settings.getFormat().setDelimiter('|');
parserSettings.setRowProcessor(rowProcessor);
parserSettings.setHeaderExtractionEnabled(true);

CsvParser parser = new CsvParser(parserSettings);

//Parsing is started here.
//this submits all rows parsed from the input to the BeanListProcessor
parser.parse(new FileReader(new File("/examples/bean_test.csv"))); 

List<SUREDataBean> beans = rowProcessor.getBeans();
```

Disclosure: I am the author of this library. It's open-source and free (Apache V2.0 license).